# E-mail notifications to specific user roles based on events in calendar

Tags: 8, notifications

I'm looking for a way/module to send an e-mail notification to users if an event is added to a calendar. Also a weekly reminder of the upcoming events that will take place next week. I'm not sure if this is possible with the Rules module or is this something I should do with cron?

Drupal version: 8.6.7

Comment: new event: no need for cron, weekly: needs cron, D8 rules is not stable, look for a module called: business rules for D8, has a youtube tutorial, post your answer when done. good luck

Comment: For weekly emails you can create a custom drush command and use crontab.
Where is this calendar?